# Issues creating tables with InfiniDB

Tags: mysql, sql, infinidb

I am attempting to create this table in InfiniDB:

```
CREATE TABLE dimension.date (
  date_id int(8), -- 20120512
  `date` date, -- 2012-05-12
  day tinyint, -- 12
  day_of_week tinyint, -- 6 (sunday being 0)
  weekday varchar(10), -- Saturday
  week tinyint,
  month tinyint,
  month_name varchar(20),
  quarter tinyint,
  year smallint
) ENGINE=infinidb;
```

and it is providing me with this error:

> Error Code: 138. The syntax or the data type(s) is not supported by
>   InfiniDB. Please check the InfiniDB syntax guide for supported syntax
>   or data types.

Yet this table can be created without issues:

```
CREATE TABLE dimension.time (
  time_id smallint(4),
  time_12 char(4), -- e.g. 12:15
  time_24 char(4), -- e.g. 00:15
  hour tinyint,
  minute tinyint,
  period char(2) -- AM or PM
) ENGINE=infinidb;
```

I even tried creating this but it generated the same error as above:

> CREATE TABLE dimension.date (date_id int(8)) ENGINE=infinidb;

Any ideas?

Comment: `"Please check the InfiniDB syntax guide"` Did you do that?

Comment: Have you tried `date_id int`, without the `(8)`?

Comment: You also have `dimension.date`. Perhaps `date` is a reserved keyword?

Comment: @ypercube So I have figured out that you cannot create a table or column named date even if you wrap it with ticks. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: So, `CREATE TABLE dimension.\`date\` (date_id int(8)) ENGINE=infinidb;` produces the same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InfiniDB is not able to create a field called 'date', if you try

```
   CREATE TABLE dimension.date (
      date_id int(8), -- 20120512
      date_ date, -- 2012-05-12
      day tinyint, -- 12
      day_of_week tinyint, -- 6 (sunday being 0)
      weekday varchar(10), -- Saturday
      week tinyint,
      month tinyint,
      month_name varchar(20),
      quarter tinyint,
      year smallint
    ) ENGINE=infinidb;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE dimension.`date_` (date_id int(8)) ENGINE=infinidb;
```

everything must work just fine.